# Period Seperated Value - Seperate Using Standard Excel Functions/Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a cell currently with the value:

17-FEB-2017 00:00:00.KH420.NR.....SO51641.21-FEB-2017.

Between each '.', there is a perceived value that needs extracted and put into a column.

I need to extract the 'SO516141' value using standard excel functions as well as the 21-Feb-2017 using standard excel functions.

Currently for the '17-FEB-2017' value, I have the formula =LEFT(A2,SEARCH(".",A2,1)-1)

And for the 'KH420' value, I have the formula:
=MID(A2, SEARCH(".",A2) + 1, SEARCH(".",A2,SEARCH(".",A2)+1) - SEARCH(".",A2) - 1)

I cannot figure out how to extract the last two values. I do not want to extract the values by using this type of method - Example (=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,20),7))

Comment: Is it not possible to use text to columns and use . as a delimeter? or is data not in a predictable structure?

Comment: It is not possible. I would have done it through that standard functionality if it was possible. There is a long story of why I can't use that, but I wanted to solve this problem using only excel standard functions/formula. It's too bad excel doesn't use "split", only in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

EDIT:
Use these consolidated versions to get the two values:
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",199)),499),199)," ","")

=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",199)),499),299)," ","")

[image]